# Smooth curve from two known points with known normal vectors

Tags: curves

I have two points, $P_1:(X_1, Y_1)$ and $P_2:(X_2, Y_2)$, with their normal vectors, $n_1$ and $n_2$.

I wish to find an equation for a smooth curve between the points.

[image: Picture]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried Bézier curves? Are parametric curves even acceptable to you?

Comment: Yes, parametric curves are acceptable. Had no idea about Beizer curve, but I found a good page which describes it. Thank you! Link to the page for those who are interested: https://javascript.info/bezier-curve